# Pre-checking collection of model objects used as check boxes with Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

So I've got some objects that I'm passing as a collection:

```
@things = Thing.all
```

And in my view:

```
<%= f.input :things, :collection => @things, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

Is there any way to specify which of the objects should already be checked when the view is loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller's "new" action, you want to initialise the form object with the values you want by default:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.things = [@one_thing, @another_thing]
end
```

This can also be done as an `after_initialize` hook in the model itself.